# how to take char input before int input in java?

Tags: java, string, char, inputstream

```
public class Pack1 {   
    public static void main(String ar[]) throws IOException { 
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      System.out.println("enter the character");
      char c=(char)br.read();
      System.out.println(c);
      System.out.println("enter the integer");
      long l=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      System.out.println("long l="+l);

      System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: i want to take char input first and then int input but it is showing number format exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the user types `X` and presses Enter on the first question, then types `123` and presses Enter on the second question, that would mean that the input stream contains the following characters:

```
X  <CR>  1  2  3  <CR>
```

When you call `read()`, you only read the `X`. When you then call `readLine()`, you read the `<CR>` and get a blank string back.

The `1 2 3 <CR>` is still sitting unread in the input stream.

Solution: Call `readLine()` after reading the `X` to skip past the rest of the line, *or* use `readLine()` to read the `X` as a `String`, instead of as a `char`.

FYI: This is the exact same problem people keep having when using `Scanner` and mixing calls to `nextLine()` with calls to other `nextXxx()` methods, like `nextInt()`.

Comment: so whenever i have to take char input i have to take input as string and then select the first character..?

Comment: You are prompting the user in a line-oriented manner, e.g. type answer, press Enter, type answer, press Enter, so you should read the input in a line-oriented manner too, especially if you only ask for one value at a time. --- Also, remember to validate, e.g. if user presses Enter without typing anything, then what? Or types `abc` when you asked for a number.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
long l=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

to :

```
long l=Long.parseLong(br.readLine(), 10);
```

This is because you are trying to convert the String to Long and not an Integer type.